# How to remove random header from Azure Data factory lookup activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am querying an Azure SQL table in ADF Lookup activity
My query looks like this

@concat('select distinct ltrim(rtrim(copay)) as column1 from ',item().TABLE_NAME,' where column1  is not null for json auto')

The output in Preview option looks like below

[image: Preview of Lookup]

I want to remove highlited random JSON header from output

I am passing this value to Web API CALL and I need value inside Square brackets

activity('GetLookupValues').output.value[0]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap the JSON query in a CAST statement.

```
@concat( 'SELECT CAST( (SELECT DISTINCT t.CoPay AS column1 FROM ', item().TABLE_NAME, ' t WHERE t.CoPay IS NOT NULL FOR JSON AUTO) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))')
```